# Print a specific number on a weird table

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a table which consists of nonnegative integers that are layed out in this manner: Each element in the table is the minimum value that does not appear to its left or above it. Here's an example of a 6x6 grid:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 0 3 2 5 4
2 3 0 1 6 7
3 2 1 0 7 6
4 5 6 7 0 1
5 4 7 6 1 0
```

The first row and column begin with 0 1 2 3 4 5... In coordinates (x,x) is always a 0, as you can see. On each tile after that, you have to place the smallest positive number that doesn't already exist on the same row or column. Much like in a sudoku-puzzle: There cannot be a number twice on the same row and column.

Now I have to print the number in the given coordinates (y,x). For example [2, 5] = 5

I came up with a working solution, but it takes way too much memory and time, and I just know there's another way of doing this. My time limit is 1 second, and the coordinates I have to find the number at can go up to (1000000, 1000000).

Here's my code at the moment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int y, x, grid_size;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > grid;

    std::cin >> y >> x; // input the coordinates we're looking for

    grid.resize(y, std::vector<int>(x, 0)); // resize the vector and initialize every tile to 0

    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            int num = 1;

            if(i != j) { // to keep the zero-diagonal

                for(int h = 0; h < y; h++)
                    for(int k = 0; k < x; k++) { // scan the current row and column
                        if(grid[h][j] == num || grid[i][k] == num) { // if we encounter the current num
                            num++;                                   // on the same row or column, increment num
                            h = -1; // scan the same row and column again
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                grid[i][j] = num; // assign the smallest number possible to the current tile

            }
        }

    /*for(int i = 0; i < y; i++) {            // print the grid
        for(int j = 0; j < x; j++)            // for debugging
            std::cout << grid[i][j] << " ";   // reasons

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }*/

    std::cout << grid[y-1][x-1] << std::endl; // print the tile number at the requested coordinates
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So what should I do? Is this easier than I think it is?

Comment: Are the numbers in the grid always following the pattern in your sample? Then you don't need to instantiate it in memory at all, but the number at the given coordinates can be simply calculated using an appropriate formula.

Comment: It's not trivial, but it certainly can be done without creating a table in memory. You have to find out how the numbers are layed out in the next rows and columns.

Comment: I've been scratching my head with my pencil and a piece of paper for an hour or so. I know it's definitely not going to fit into any array or anything.. Just can't come up with the formula

Comment: Are the rows always following the same pattern? i.e. is the next row always the previous one shifted by one position?

Comment: ah, sorry. Yes the numbers are always following the same pattern

Comment: The pattern seems to break down a little on the third row though where you start to use a different set of digits (introducing 6 and 7 and dropping 4 and 5). What are the rules exactly?

Comment: The first row and column begin with 0 1 2 3 4 5... In coordinates (x,x) is always a 0, as you can see. On each tile after that, you have to place the smallest positive number that doesn't already exist on the same row or column. Much like in a sudoku-puzzle: There cannot be a number twice on the same row and column.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja how do you explain 6 and 7 as mentioned in PaulMitchell's comment then?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a [(reduced) Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Comment: @izomorphius if you follow the algorithm, the 6 and 7 actually make sense there

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja your comment should be in the question. Precise description of how the matrix is filled is essential to the question.

Comment: Oh. I thought I did, but it is a little vaguely explained.

Comment: There are many ways to construct such a table. If you have a table with those properties, you can freely switch any two columns or any two rows and it will retain those properties.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja: I have attempted to clarify the question, let me know if this is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize your question: You have a table where each element is the minimum nonnegative integer that does not appear to its left or above. You need to find the element at position (x,y).

The result is surprisingly simple: If `x` and `y` are 0-based, then the element at (x,y) is `x XOR y`. This matches the table you have posted. I have [verified](http://ideone.com/F6jBzs) it experimentally for a 200x200 table.

**The proof:**

It's easy to see that the same number won't appear twice on the same row or column, because if x<sub>1</sub>^y = x<sub>2</sub>^y then necessarily x<sub>1</sub>=x<sub>2</sub>.

To see that `x^y` is minimal: Let `a` be a number smaller than `x^y`. Let `i` be the index (from the right) of the leftmost bit where `a` differs from `x^y`. The `i`th bit of `a` must be 0 and the `i`th bit of `x^y` must be 1.

Therefore, either `x` or `y` must have 0 in the `i`th bit. Suppose WLOG it was `x` that had 0. Represent `x` and `y` as:

```
x = A0B
y = C1D
```

Where A,B,C,D are sequences of bits, and B and D are `i` bits long. Since the leftmost bits of `a` are the same as those in `x^y`:

```
a^x = C0E
```

Where E is a sequence of `i` bits. So we can see that `a^x < y`. The value that appered in the `(a^x)`th row on the same column was: `(a^x)^x = a`. So the value `a` must have already appeared in the same row (or column, if it was `y` that had 0 in the `i`th bit). This is true for any value smaller than `x^y`, so `x^y` is indeed the minimum possible value.

Comment: this would be really cool. The way I would prove this theory empirically is by writing a brute-force solution for upto say 50 and if your solution works for all those tables than you really **are** a genius :)

Comment: You can prove it by generating columns and rows of various grid sizes with this method and check them for meeting the conditions.

Comment: @g-makulik: I wouldn't call that "proving", I'd prefer a mathematical proof. I've verified it now for at least up to a 200x200 table.

Comment: I tested it and it works. Your solution is correct and I'm dumbfounded. Verified with a 1000000x1000000 table (don't ask where I got it). I don't understand it. Exactly what does x^y do?

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja: I've managed to prove it but the proof is more complicated than I would have liked. `x^y` is the bitwise XOR of x and y, it can appear in surprising places such as the solution to the [game of Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim)